# Angular 7 finally does not works

Tags: angular

I have an issue related with finally, how to resolve it? I tried to import it like below, but it does not works, then I also checked that solution:
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally'` or even `import 'rxjs/operator'`. When I hover on the finally to see what is the issue it says `'finally' does not exists on type 'Observable<Object>'.` Any ideas how to solve it?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { finally } from 'rxjs/operator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private app: AppService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
      this.app.authenticate(undefined, undefined);
  }

  logout() {
    this.http.post('logout', {}).finally(() => {
        this.app.authenticated = false;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }).subscribe();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using rxjs6. So you have to use [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) and use `pipe` with the operator like this:

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

logout() {
  this.http.post('logout', {}).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.app.authenticated = false;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We now use `finalize` instead of `finally`

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators'

observable().pipe( finalize());
```